# Code running forever in C — what did I do wrong?

Tags: c

I want to know why when running this code I get an infinite output. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num;
    printf(" enter a number\n");
    scanf(" %d", &num);
    for( num = 0 ; num <= 10 ; num+=num){
        printf(" %d",num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<num; i++) printf(" %d",i);`

Comment: That's a different question. Once you get this question sorted out, and accept an answer, then you can start a new question about printing a table. But be sure to try it yourself first. Hint: you need two `for` loops. The outer loop counts rows in the table and the inner loop counts columns.

Comment: As you print `num` in the loop: did you observe anything suspicious? What does the observation tell about if the terminating condition of the `for` (2nd expression inside the parentheses)?

Answer (score 2):

`num+= num` never incrementing the `num`. It is always adding `0` to `0`. Also `num = 0` in `for` loop overriding user input for `num`.

Answer (score 1):

num+=num always adds 0 to 0(num) and hence the value of num never increments. Thus num always less than 10 and loop never exits.

Answer (score 0):

while num++ would lead to num > 0, `num += num` with initial `num = 0` what you get is `num += 0`, and the loop never reaches 10. Just use `num++`

Answer (score 0):

```
int num;
printf(" enter a number\n");
scanf(" %d", &num);
for( num = 0 ; num <= 10 ; num++){
    printf(" %d",num);
    }
```

num+=num meaning is num=num+num and num start from 0 so num=0 always so go in infinite loop.change it `num++`.